# Extract href from specific tr element using XPath

Tags: xpath

Given the following HTML code :

```html
<tr>
<th scope="row" class="navbox-group">Family</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-even hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/wiki/Andrew_Parker_Bowles" title="Andrew Parker Bowles">Andrew Parker Bowles</a> <small>(first husband)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Tom_Parker_Bowles" title="Tom Parker Bowles">Tom Parker Bowles</a> <small>(son)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Laura_Lopes" title="Laura Lopes">Laura Lopes</a> <small>(daughter)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Charles,_Prince_of_Wales" title="Charles, Prince of Wales">Charles, Prince of Wales</a> <small>(second husband)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Bruce_Shand" title="Bruce Shand">Bruce Shand</a> <small>(father)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Rosalind_Shand" title="Rosalind Shand">Rosalind Shand</a> <small>(mother)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Annabel_Elliot" title="Annabel Elliot">Annabel Elliot</a> <small>(sister)</small></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Mark_Shand" title="Mark Shand">Mark Shand</a> <small>(brother)</small></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get all the href within the tr element , but only from tr elements that contains :

```html
<th scope="row" class="navbox-group">Family</th>
```

(Where th='Family')

I try to write the following XPath :

"//tr[@th='Family']//a/@href"

But I don't get any href.

Thanks a lot.

Shany

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: `[@th='Family']` means "having a `th` attribute with value `Family`", but `th` isn't an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `XPath`:

```
//tr[th="Family"]//@href
```

It should allow you to get list of links from `tr` that contains `th` with text `"Family"`